# Initializing and loading a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have Custom uitableviewcell: ScrollViewCell

I want to know what the difference is between the following code

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScrollViewCell";
ScrollViewCell *cell = (ScrollViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    //***** WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THIS CODE AND..
    NSArray *xibObj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScrollViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObj in xibObj){
        if ([currentObj isKindOfClass:[ScrollViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (ScrollViewCell *) currentObj;
        }
    }
    //***** ..THIS CODE
    cell = [[ScrollViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example will load a cell from a `.xib` file in your application's bundle. Each cell can handle it's own code, and behaves a lot like a `UIViewController`. This approach can get complicated when you try and load data from an array. You have to pass the object you're getting data out of to the cell, and have a very clear design before you start coding.

The other method allocates an empty instance of the `UITableViewCell` class as normal. This approach is typically used for programmatic configuration of the cells. You'll probably see this one in most places.

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila